# Timer run even if Activity stops

Tags: android, countdowntimer

have started my timer from the onCreate method. Even If My activity stops ,Timer keeps Running. How it is possible?

Toast in onTick() method diplays, Thread is main thread. I thought , when Activity stops  Main thread will stop. can anyone give the explanation about this.

**CustomCountDownTimer.java**

```
private class CustomCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer
    {
        public CustomCountDownTimer(long millisInFuture,long countDownInterval)
        {
            super(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long seconds=millisUntilFinished/1000;
        long hours=seconds/(60*60);
        long remainingSeconds=seconds%(60*60);
        long minutes=remainingSeconds/60;
        remainingSeconds=remainingSeconds%60; 

        Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, Thread.currentThread().getName()+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        btnStatusMessage.setText(hours+" hr "+minutes+" min "); 

        }
```

Comment: call `cancel()` in `onPause()`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: I want to know , why timer keeps running even if my activity stops.is it running in the background?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/os/CountDownTimer.java. check this

Comment: just log the time in `onTick`. check the logcat whether it still runs after `onPause()`. override `onStop` and `onDestroy` log some info there. Now check the logcat you will know yourself

Comment: yes . I did this , In my Logcat , It is showing the time continuosly , even if my activity stops. I want to run the timer , even my activity stops. I am getting the expected output. But i dont know how Timer runs even if activity stops. Is this background service(apart from the main thread)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146783/countdowntimer-updating-and-blocking. call cancel in `onPause` that should stop the count down timer. From the grepcode link i don't see any thread used to start the timer.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html. also check the topic under threads.

Comment: @Raghunandan : Thank u so much for your response. I will study first about how the thread works during the activity life cycle. Then If I still have doubts , i will make a seperate question.

Answer (score 1):

The timer is not related to the Activity. You need to stop it in one of the Activity's state methods (onPause/onStop/etc').

Comment: Activity runs in main thread. so is Timer running in seperate thread?

Comment: @saravanan no http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/os/CountDownTimer.java

Comment: @saravanan when you say "when Activity stops Main thread will stop" do you mean activity paused or activity destoryed?

Comment: I mentioned for Activity paused or stopped.not for destroyed. I want to know whether the Main thread will stop when activity pauses or stops.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this code to your activity.

```
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    timer.cancel();  
}
```

Comment: timer.cancel() should be before super.onDestroy() method

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Use flage to check timer is already running

if (!timerHasStarted) {
    countDownTimer.start();
    timerHasStarted = true;
    btnStatusMessage.setText("STOP");
    } else {
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    timerHasStarted = false;
    btnStatusMessage.setText("RESTART");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

just add to your activity

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);//mHandler (Handler) and mUpdateTimeTask (Runnable)
}
```

dont forget to add this too:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```

before you call the intent too

home this will help you